# PHP Date Formatting not working wen using date_format()

Tags: php

I have a date field I'm pulling from WordPress, where the default format is:

16/12/2016

Been a while since I played with PHP, but I remember the way to format dates was: `echo date_format($date,"[format syntax]");`

But when I do

```
$date = myWPField;
echo date_format($date,"F d, y");
```

If doesn't display the date.

What am I missing. Has this changed?

Comment: is there any error?  is the myWPField DateTime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date is not an acceptable format in date_create like `mm/dd/yy(yy)` or `mm-dd-yy(yy)`

Use php `DateTime::createFromFormat` function instead this function can detect what format you

> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)
>       DateTime::createFromFormat -- date_create_from_format — Parses a time string according to a specified format

```
$date = '16/12/2016';
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('F d, y');
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/702466)

Answer (score 1):

when create data format form string use slash format, it's in the mm/dd/yy(yy) format. So in you code your first 16 is not allowed by default, you have to specify in what format to create from the string.

Note that when you create a new date object using a format with slashes and dashes (eg `02-02-2012 or 02/02/2012`) it must be in the `mm/dd/yy(yy)` or `mm-dd-yy(yy)` format (rather than british format `dd/mm/yy`)! Months always before years (the american style) otherwise you'll get an incorrect date and may get an error like the one above (where PHP is crashing on trying to decode a 13th month).