# Create datetime form dd/mm/yy(yy)

Tags: datetime-format

I try to create datetime form dd/mm/yy(yy), but with no success?

code:

```
var_dump(date_create("22/12/2016"));
```

or

```
var_dump(strtotime("22/12/2016"));
```

neither works. This is the [demo](https://eval.in/702443). Why I cannot create from this format?

Comment: 3rd note: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes

Comment: weird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274672/php-date-formatting-not-working-wen-using-date-format/41274789#41274789

Comment: From the php.net reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php - it assumes with the / separator that you are doing american style dates, so mm/dd/yyyy.  However, you are using euro style, dd/mm/yyyy but the strtotime() expects those to be in dd-mm-yyyy form.  you'll need to pull it apart and put it in one of the formats strtotime expects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `date_create` convert your date into an acceptable date format
using

> DateTime::createFromFormat
>   (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)
>   DateTime::createFromFormat -- date_create_from_format — Parses a time string according to a specified format

```
var_dump(date_create(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "22/12/2016")->format('Y-m-d')));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/702463)